# Windows system key

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I am using `SetWindowsHookEx` to modify `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` events.
My goal is to substitute some Alt key combinations by another key events without Alt modifier for the whole system.
For example: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> generates DownArrow event.
I am following this strategy: I catch the key event with Alt modifier and generate corresponding event.
For example, if I catch <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> pressed event,

```
keybd_event(altVirtualKey,
            altScanCode,
            2,
            0); // Release alt key
keybd_event(downArrowVirtualKey,
            downArrowScanCode,
            0,
            0); // Press down arrow
```

The problem with this idea is that when I release alt, most of applications react badly to this, like opening menus, losing selection, focus, ... I found that this is related to `WM_SYSTEMUP` event. By I don't know how to prevent it to appear.

Any ideas?